# Not getting the right results using GROUP_CONCAT in query

Tags: mysql

I have 7 tables to work with inside a query:

```
tb_post, tb_spots, users, td_sports, tb_spot_types, tb_users_sports, tb_post_media
```

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT po.id_post AS id_post, 
po.description_post as description_post,
 sp.id_spot as id_spot, 
po.date_post as date_post,
 u.id AS userid, 
u.user_type As tipousuario, 
u.username AS username, 
spo.id_sport AS sportid, 
spo.sport_icon as sporticon, 
st.logo_spot_type as spottypelogo, 
sp.city_spot AS city_spot, 
sp.country_spot AS country_spot, 
sp.latitud_spot as latitudspot,
 sp.longitud_spot as longitudspot,
 sp.short_name AS spotshortname, 
sp.verified_spot AS spotverificado, 
 u.profile_image AS profile_image,
sp.verified_spot_by as spotverificadopor,
 uv.id AS spotverificador,
 uv.user_type AS spotverificadornivel,
 pm.media_type AS mediatype,
 pm.media_file AS mediafile,

GROUP_CONCAT(tus.user_sport_sport) sportsdelusuario,
GROUP_CONCAT(logosp.sport_icon) sportsdelusuariologos,
GROUP_CONCAT(pm.media_file) mediapost,
GROUP_CONCAT(pm.media_type) mediaposttype

FROM tb_posts po 

LEFT JOIN tb_spots sp ON po.spot_post = sp.id_spot 
LEFT JOIN users u ON po.uploaded_by_post = u.id 
LEFT JOIN tb_sports spo ON sp.sport_spot = spo.id_sport
LEFT JOIN tb_spot_types st ON sp.type_spot = st.id_spot_type
LEFT JOIN users uv ON sp.verified_spot_by = uv.id
LEFT JOIN tb_users_sports tus ON tus.user_sport_user = u.id
LEFT JOIN tb_sports logosp ON logosp.id_sport = tus.user_sport_sport
LEFT JOIN tb_post_media pm  ON pm.media_post = po.id_post 

WHERE po.status = 1
GROUP BY po.id_post,uv.id
```

I am having problems with some of the GROUP_CONCAT groups:

`GROUP_CONCAT(tus.user_sport_sport) sportsdelusuario` is giving me the right items but repeated, all items twice

`GROUP_CONCAT(logosp.sport_icon) sportsdelusuariologos` is giving me the right items but repeated, all items twice

`GROUP_CONCAT(pm.media_file) mediapost` is giving me the right items but repeated four times

`GROUP_CONCAT(pm.media_type) mediaposttype` s giving me the right items but repeated four times

I can put here all tables structures if you need them.

Comment: You generally cannot expect appropriate results from aggregate functions in queries where multiple, unrelated 1-to-many relations are involved.

Comment: @Uueerdo, and could I get the desired strings arrays using selects from the needed tables as part of the output items?

Comment: If you mean subqueries in the SELECT, yes that works; but it requires correlated subqueries that have to be executed for each row of the outer SELECT. I'd suggest a subqueries in the FROM, that group on your original join condition, that are then joined as if they were the table.

Comment: I've been dabbling with sql for 10 years or so. I've not yet had cause to use GROUP_CONCAT, so I'm always intrigued when others do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple one-to-many relations JOINed in a query have a multiplicative affect on aggregation results; the standard solution is subqueries:

You can change

```
GROUP_CONCAT(pm.media_type) mediaposttype
...
LEFT JOIN tb_post_media pm  ON pm.media_post = po.id_post
```

to

```
pm.mediaposttype
...
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT media_post, GROUP_CONCAT(media_type) AS mediaposttype 
   FROM tb_post_media 
   GROUP BY media_post
) AS pm ON pm.media_post = po.id_post
```

If tb_post_media is very big, and the `po.status = 1` condition in the outer query would significantly reduce the results of the subquery, it can be worth replicating the original join within the subquery to filter down it's results.

Similarly, the correlated version I mentioned in the comments can also be more performant if the outer query has relatively few results. (Calculating the GROUP_CONCAT() for each individually can cost less than calculating it for all once if you would only actually using very few of the results of the latter).

Comment: thank you, but the answer from Peterhe works for me

Comment: Yes, that works too in this case, but some would argue it masks the problem rather than solves it. Don't get me wrong, I'd go with that if I was pressed for time and had a lot of other stuff to do; but it will not work for things like SUM or in situations where you would actually want multiple matches to show up in the resulting string the correct number of times.

Comment: @Uuerdo, thank you for your comments, I do really appreciate it, but you are right, I will check the current solution for a time, and see if it works, if not, then I will need to test your proposal.

Comment: @Uueerdo my answer is based on the question. If the question is about SUM or other situation, the answer will be different. Your answer works but using subqueries. Mysql query optimizer is not good at optimizing subqueries, and can get performance issue if subqueries are used.

Comment: @PeterHe Yeah, I wasn't trying to steal your credit or anything, just pointing out the differences; DISTINCT on the results of multiple joins involving independent 1:N relations can quickly (depending on how big N is and how many relations are involved) become more costly than joining to subqueries that effectively convert them to 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

or just add DISTINCT to all the group_concat, e.g., GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pm.media_type)

Comment: @mvasco Not sure why you unaccepted it? This answers exactly what you asked.